# Formula to reference description in separate sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a formula that is trying to check if a code in a cell matches a code in a list in column A of sheet "references", if it does, get the description of the code in column B of sheet "references". This formula is inside a cell of a separate sheet. When I populate the correct code in cell F7, it returns #N/A, rather than the value of the code description in column B of sheet "references".

Here is the formula:    `=IF(F7="","",IF(AND(COUNTIF(reference!$A:$A,JE!F7)>0),VLOOKUP(JE!F7,reference!B:B,2,FALSE), "#N/A"))`

Can anyone help me out. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: change `reference!B:B` in the vlookup to `reference!A:B`  And you do not need the `AND(` as you are only checking one thing.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks, Scott! I appreciate your feedback.